# I am getting wrong north and east values after cartographic projection using PROJ library in C++

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, utm

I am getting incorrect north and east values after cartographic projection from global WGS84 crs(i.e., EPSG:4326) to CRS Korean 1985/West Belt using PROJ C++ library. I got an error of approx. 1.5 cm along north and east when I checked in SurPad application using same parameters as below. Am I missing any parameters or did I do anything wrong?

```c
int main()
{

    // Define the initial point
    PJ_COORD initialPoint;

    //------Korean -------
    initialPoint.lpz.lam = 127.18;
    initialPoint.lpz.phi = 37.34;
    initialPoint.lpz.z = 114.651;

    PJ *Src = proj_create(NULL, "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84  +no_defs +type=crs");
    PJ *Targcopy = proj_create(NULL, "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=125 +k=1 +x_0=200000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=Bessel +towgs84=125.905,-478.377,-658.757,2.166,2.284,-1.866,-1.844 +approx +units=m +no_defs +type=crs");
    auto c2c = proj_create_crs_to_crs_from_pj(NULL, Src, Targcopy, NULL, NULL);


    PJ_COORD FinalPoint = proj_trans(c2c, PJ_FWD, initialPoint);

    printf("Output 2D northing: %.3f\n easting: %.3f\n height: %.3f \n", FinalPoint.xy.y, FinalPoint.xy.x, FinalPoint.xyz.z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you getting and what do you expect to get? Please edit your question with the additional info.

Comment: You call 1.5 cm as an error. I would call it as a small inaccuracy.

Comment: Targcopy is missing a datum

Comment: @MikeT My apologies. Actually "+datum =" shouldn't be written since I am representing the datum of Targcopy with +towgs84. It's a typo mistake. However, I did my calculation without this typo error in my code. Based on that only, my question is about. I observed one thing that my values are exactly matched to surpad when I set +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 in Targcopy and set all datum transform values to zero in the surpad application. But I am getting errors only when I set datum transform values to non-zero values.